# Can hold out approach perform better than k fold cv?

Tags: r, artificial-intelligence, resampling

```
# when i apply hold out approch
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(1)
fit <- randomForest(y~.,data=q.train, mtry = 28, importance = T)
fit
# i got accuracy 0.8626 in test set

# k fold cv
mycontrol = trainControl(method = "cv", number=10, savePrediction = "final",
                         classProbs = T, allowParallel = T)
fit2 = train(y~., data = q.train, method = "rf", trControl = mycontrol, tuneLength = 10, 
               preProc = c("center", "scale"))
fit2
# i got accuracy 0.8531 in test set
```

Should I choose hold out approach for the final model rather than k fold cv?
Size of training set is about 800, very small.

Comment: You're probably seeing random variation. In generation CV will be better.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.